# Android Popup Window Full Screen

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-fullscreen

I want to create a popupwindow for fullscreen

i've used the following :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

layoutt = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loginto,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.window1));

pwindow = new PopupWindow(layoutt,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
```

This covers the action bar but not the full screen..

Also LayuotParams.WRAP_CONTENT is supported by api 11+ . i need the solution to work from api level 8.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the full screen you have to pass the `MATCH_PARENT` params instead of `WRAP_CONTENT`

```
pwindow = new PopupWindow(layout,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,true);
```

Comment: Does that warning need to be taken into account? it says           Field requires API level 11 (current min is 8):   android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams#FILL_PARENT

Comment: @mkumar it's warning only so no need to worry at all. you can take `FILL_PARENT` OR `MATCH_PARENT` what ever you like...  :)

Comment: This is deprecated, any other way of doing this?

Comment: `FILL_PARENT` was renamed to `MATCH_PARENT` in earlier APIs, so just use the latter and everything will be fine

Answer (score 2):

**JAVA Version**

```
 View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_complete_pause_work,null,false);

 PopupWindow popupWindow=new PopupWindow(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

 popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
```

**Kotlin Version:**

```
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null, false)

val popupWindow = PopupWindow(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
```

Comment: In Kotlin, I would suggest to use "val" when possible - as stated in official recommendations. In this case, if you know that "popupWindow" will be a valid instance of the PopupWindow class, there is no need to define it as variable, which will be a nullable type. With "val", it is always assigned, so you don't even need the "?" operator to check for null values.

Comment: In this case, you do not need the "?" to check if popupWindow is null. It can be accessed directly :)